# Why do I have to enclose a Javascript function call in an anonymous function for it to not be called immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, anonymous-function

I have this Javascript function:

```
function Card(term, def, terms, curTerm) {
    this.term = term;
    this.def = def;
    this.terms = terms;
    this.curTerm = curTerm;

    this.show = function() {
        that = this;
        var html = createCard(that.term, that.def);
        $('body').append(html);
        $('input[type=text]').focus();
        $('.answer').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            answer = $(this).parent().serializeArray()[0].value;

            // answer correct
            if (that.term === answer) {
                $('.card').addClass('correct');
                $('form').replaceWith('<h2>Correct! ' + that.term + '</h2>');
                setTimeout(function () {that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1);}, 1500);

            // answer incorrect
            } else {
                $('.card').addClass('incorrect');
                $('form').replaceWith('<h2>Incorrect! ' + that.term + '</h2>');
                setTimeout(function () {that.destroy(terms, curTerm);}, 1500);
            }
        });
    };
```

The line I am having issues with is `setTimeout(function () {that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1);}, 1500);`. Originally I had `setTimeout(that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1), 1500);`, but it didn't set the timeout it just called `that.destroy`. Why does it not call it immediately when put in the anonymous function? Does this have anything to do with closures? because it seems like I am having to create a closure, but I haven't figured out enough about them to know for sure.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you are passing in a function, which is what setTimeout expects. `setTimeout(that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1), 1500);` executes `destroy` immediately, and passes in the return value of `destroy` to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first `setTimeout()` call, this:

```
that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1)
```

is a function call expression.  It's evaluated in order to build the set of parameter values to call `setTimeout()`.

When you wrap it in an anonymous function, that (anonymous) function is **not** called, because you don't suffix it with the function call operator — the parenthesized list of parameters.

Thus:  an expression of the form

```
something ( p1, p2, ... pn )
```

means to invoke the function referenced by "something" after evaluating each of the parameters in the argument list, and then use that value as the larger expression context proceeds.  It **always** means that in JavaScript. There's no syntax to say "here's the function I want you to call later, and some parameters to pass".  (There's a *function* to do that now — `.bind()` on the Function prototype — but no special *syntax*.)

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense - not sure why I didn't think of that before. So with .bind() if I were to say `that.destroy(terms, curTerm + 1).bind()` would that keep it from executing till `setTimeout()` is called?

Comment: @chromedude No, to use `.bind()` you'd call `that.destroy.bind(that, terms, curTerm + 1)` and pass that to setTimeout. That call returns a function that, when called, invokes the "destroy" function.

Answer (score 1):

This is just part of the JavaScript syntax.

`function name() {}` declares a function and `name()` calls it.  You can also call anonymous functions immediately with the syntax `(function (){})()`.

Also note that you can pass function *names* where an anonymous function would otherwise be appropriate, as in:

```
setTimeout(that.destroy, 1500)
```

Of course you can't change the arguments in that case.

Answer (score 1):

When the JavaScript interpreter sees `someFunction(param)`, it immediately calls the method `someFunction` and passes it the parameter `param`. In other words, when you do:

```
setTimeout(someFunction(param), 1000);
```

... you're passing setTimeout the result of someFunction(param). You can instead pass someFunction as a first-class member like this:

```
setTimeout(someFunction, 1000, param);
```

This way, you're passing setTimeout the definition of someFunction. Beware that passing `param` in this case won't work in IE.

Also, see http://www.helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/.